# Adding jQuery in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I want to use a template in my react app there is some jquery in it and it's referenced by a function `$('#steps_user').modalSteps()`.
I installed jquery by npm install jquery but it didn't help and says modalSteps() is not a function!
it's necessary to use the the jquery. by the way I have imported my jquery file in the public/index.html

this is my jquery file:

```
/* global jQuery */

(function($){
    'use strict';

$.fn.modalSteps = function(options){
    var $modal = this;

    var validCallbacks = function(){
        var everyStepCallback = settings.callbacks['*'];

        if (everyStepCallback !== undefined && typeof(everyStepCallback) !== 'function'){
            throw 'everyStepCallback is not a function! I need a function';
        }

        if (typeof(settings.completeCallback) !== 'function') {
            throw 'completeCallback is not a function! I need a function';
        }

        for(var step in settings.callbacks){
            if (settings.callbacks.hasOwnProperty(step)){
                var callback = settings.callbacks[step];

                if (step !== '*' && callback !== undefined && typeof(callback) !== 'function'){
                    throw 'Step ' + step + ' callback must be a function';
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var executeCallback = function(callback){
        if (callback !== undefined && typeof(callback) === 'function'){
            callback();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    $modal
        .on('show.bs.modal', function(){
            var $modalFooter = $modal.find('.modal-footer'),
                $btnCancel = $modalFooter.find('.js-btn-step[data-orientation=cancel]'),
                $btnPrevious = $modalFooter.find('.js-btn-step[data-orientation=previous]'),
                $btnNext = $modalFooter.find('.js-btn-step[data-orientation=next]'),
                everyStepCallback = settings.callbacks['*'],
                stepCallback = settings.callbacks['1'],
                actualStep,
                $actualStep,
                titleStep,
                $titleStepSpan,
                nextStep;

            if (settings.disableNextButton){
                $btnNext.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            $btnPrevious.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            validCallbacks();
            executeCallback(everyStepCallback);
            executeCallback(stepCallback);

            // Setting buttons
            $btnCancel.html(settings.btnCancelHtml);
            $btnPrevious.html(settings.btnPreviousHtml);
            $btnNext.html(settings.btnNextHtml);

            $actualStep = $('<input>').attr({
                'type': 'hidden',
                'id': 'actual-step',
                'value': '1',
            });

            $modal.find('#actual-step').remove();
            $modal.append($actualStep);

            actualStep = 1;
            nextStep = actualStep + 1;

            $modal.find('[data-step=' + actualStep + ']').removeClass('hide');
            $btnNext.attr('data-step', nextStep);

            titleStep = $modal.find('[data-step=' + actualStep + ']').data('title');
            $titleStepSpan = $('<span>')
                                .addClass('label label-success')
                                .html(actualStep);

            $modal
                .find('.js-title-step')
                .append($titleStepSpan)
                .append(' ' + titleStep);
        })
        .on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
            var $actualStep = $modal.find('#actual-step'),
                $btnNext = $modal.find('.js-btn-step[data-orientation=next]');

            $modal
                .find('[data-step]')
                .not($modal.find('.js-btn-step'))
                .addClass('hide');

            $actualStep
                .not($modal.find('.js-btn-step'))
                .remove();

            $btnNext
                .attr('data-step', 1)
                .html(settings.btnNextHtml);

            $modal.find('.js-title-step').html('');
        });

    $modal.find('.js-btn-step').on('click', function(){
        var $btn = $(this),
            $actualStep = $modal.find('#actual-step'),
            $btnPrevious = $modal.find('.js-btn-step[data-orientation=previous]'),
            $btnNext = $modal.find('.js-btn-step[data-orientation=next]'),
            $title = $modal.find('.js-title-step'),
            orientation = $btn.data('orientation'),
            actualStep = parseInt($actualStep.val()),
            everyStepCallback = settings.callbacks['*'],
            steps,
            nextStep,
            $nextStep,
            newTitle;

        steps = $modal.find('div[data-step]').length;

        // Callback on Complete
        if ($btn.attr('data-step') === 'complete'){
            settings.completeCallback();
            $modal.modal('hide');

            return;
        }

        // Check the orientation to make logical operations with actualStep/nextStep
        if (orientation === 'next'){
            nextStep = actualStep + 1;

            $btnPrevious.attr('data-step', actualStep);
            $actualStep.val(nextStep);

        } else if (orientation === 'previous'){
            nextStep = actualStep - 1;

            $btnNext.attr('data-step', actualStep);
            $btnPrevious.attr('data-step', nextStep - 1);

            $actualStep.val(actualStep - 1);

        } else {
            $modal.modal('hide');
            return;
        }

        if (parseInt($actualStep.val()) === steps){
            $btnNext
                .attr('data-step', 'complete')
                .html(settings.btnLastStepHtml);
        } else {
            $btnNext
                .attr('data-step', nextStep)
                .html(settings.btnNextHtml);
        }

        if (settings.disableNextButton){
            $btnNext.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        // Hide and Show steps
        $modal
            .find('[data-step=' + actualStep + ']')
            .not($modal.find('.js-btn-step'))
            .addClass('hide');

        $modal
            .find('[data-step=' + nextStep + ']')
            .not($modal.find('.js-btn-step'))
            .removeClass('hide');

        // Just a check for the class of previous button
        if (parseInt($btnPrevious.attr('data-step')) > 0 ){
            $btnPrevious.removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $btnPrevious.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        if (orientation === 'previous'){
            $btnNext.removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        // Get the next step
        $nextStep = $modal.find('[data-step=' + nextStep + ']');

        // Verify if we need to unlock continue btn of the next step
        if ($nextStep.attr('data-unlock-continue')){
            $btnNext.removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        // Set the title of step
        newTitle = $nextStep.attr('data-title');
        var $titleStepSpan = $('<span>')
                            .addClass('label label-success')
                            .html(nextStep);

        $title
            .html($titleStepSpan)
            .append(' ' + newTitle);

        var stepCallback = settings.callbacks[$actualStep.val()];
        executeCallback(everyStepCallback);
        executeCallback(stepCallback);
    });

    return this;
};
}(jQuery));
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use jQuery with react because react uses virtual DOM which will not work properly with jQuery installed.

Comment: Also, `.modalSteps` is not a standard jquery method and is probably added by a plugin, so you'd need that plugin as well, which may be on npm, or you may need to install by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled the the problem with react and didn't use the jQuery.

this is what i did inside my component class:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            step: 0,
            message:''
        }
    }

handleNext = () =>{

    if (this.state.step === 1 ){
        this.handleSubmit()
    }
    this.setState({
        step: 1
    })
};

handlePrevious = () =>{
    if (this.state.step === 1 ){
        this.setState({
            step: 0
        })
    }

};

handleSubmit = () =>{
    this.props.userStore.updateUser()
        .then((response)=>{
            if (response.result === 'success'){
                this.setState({
                    message: response.message
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    message: response.message
                })
            }
        })
};

render() {
        return (
              <div className="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button"
                                        className="btn btn-danger js-btn-step pull-right"
                                        data-orientation="cancel" data-dismiss="modal">ignore
                                </button>
                                <button type="button"
                                        className="btn btn-default js-btn-step"
                                        onClick={this.handlePrevious}
                                        data-orientation="previous">Previous
                                </button>
                                <button type="button"
                                        className="btn btn-success js-btn-step"
                                        onClick={this.handleNext}
                                        data-orientation="next">{this.state.step===1 ? 'submit' : 'Next'}
                                </button>
                   </div>
);
    }
```